# Domdocument find and insert

Tags: php, html, domdocument

OK , here is a html content that i have :

```
<p> .... </p>
<div id="quick_preview">
<p>the contents </p>
</div>
```

and what i want is :

```
<p> .... </p>
<div id="quick_preview">
<description>
  <p>the contents </p>
</description>
</div>
```

i  use this routine to find the `div` and create `description` tag, but i don't know how to insert `<description>` into div before `p`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($row['body']);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div)
{
    if ($div->getAttribute( "id" ) == 'quick_preview') {
        $desc_element = $dom->createElement('description');
    }
}
$dom->saveHTMLFile($html)
```

Comment: I take it that you mean `<div class="quick_preview">`, not `<div id="quick_preview">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($row['body']);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@id="quick_preview"]');
foreach ($divs as $div)
{
    $description = $dom->createElement('description');
    while ( $div->hasChildNodes() )
    {
        $description->appendChild($div->firstChild);
    }
    $div->appendChild($description);
}

$dom->saveHTMLFile($html);
```

You could drop the XPath and use `$dom->getElementById('quick_preview')` instead.

Note that you can move DOM nodes by simply appending them somewhere else in the document.

Comment: @bizzare No errors? Did you check what `$xpath->query('//div[class="quick_preview"]')` returns? -- *(Ah, there is the error, it should have been `$xpath->query('//div[@class="quick_preview"]')`, note the `@`.)*

Comment: @Tomlak the result : `<div id="quick_preview">
<p> this quick preview div</p>
<description>
</description>
</div>`

Comment: @bizzare Did you check that it at least *enters* the `foreach` loop? Also, since you've changed your question it must be `$xpath->query('//div[@id="quick_preview"]')`, very obviously. *(Side note: Apparently you are looking for a single element with an ID, so you could use `DOMDocument->getElementById()` and drop the XPath altogether.)*

Comment: @yes , but `$div->removeChild($child) ` did not works , what's wrong ?

Comment: @bizzare What does `removeChild` return?

Comment: @bizzare: Ah, the `removeChild()` breaks the `foreach` loop. I've switched to a different approach using `while`, now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks , my approach is working fine but your routine is more optimized so i accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($row['body']);
$ps = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($ps as $p)
{
    if ($p->parentNode->getAttribute( "id" ) == 'quick_preview') {
        $desc_element = $dom->createElement('description');
        $desc_element->appendChild($p);
        $divs = $xpath->query('//div[@id="quick_preview"]');
        foreach($divs as $div){
            $div->appendChild($desc_element);
        }
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```